# How do I fuse objects (like cubes and cones)?

Tags: objects

I am making a trident for a fish game where you control the currents to guide fish around. I wasn't thinking ahead and didn't use the extrude tool to add other parts and now I have to connect them. How would I fuse them together? Also, I have to put cones on the ends, so does it matter if it is a cone, a cylinder, a cube, or whatever object it is that you are fusing? Or if it is two different objects? And can you un-fuse them?

I know that this is kind of more than one question crammed into one, but it is all the same idea, right? (I was going to end it with the questions and that last one wasnt very Blender related)

Answer (score 1):

You can join two objects with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>:

[image]

Make sure that the object you want to have the modifiers for and the origin of the combined object is the last selected and the outline is lighter orange.

To separate again, <kbd>Tab</kbd> into edit mode and hit <kbd>P</kbd> > *loose parts*

*note from author: Sorry for the terrible trident model. I didn't have motivation to try harder.*
[image]

Comment: No, no! that was a great model of a trident! Better, than mine anyways. Helpful and has a better model than the author himself. Did you extrude the extra points and use loop cuts on a cylinder?

Comment: i used the "spin" tool to make the trident elbows. The points were simple cones. If the answer works for you, please accept it (the little check mark) so we can close this question as resolved. thanks--

Answer (score 0):

If you have two completely different objects like a cone and a cube you can join them into one object. This object would then still be made out of the two original submeshes (including fully or partially hidden faces).

In order to do so, select the first object, then <kbd>Shift</kbd>-select the second one and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to join them.

To separate them again (or in general create two separate meshes of any mesh) Tab into Edit Mode, select the vertices of the mesh you want to separate, press <kbd>P</kbd> and choose "Selection" or "by loose parts".

However, be aware that simply joining different objects might not necessarily be a good practice to create game models in terms of topology, polygon reduction, rigging and an overall good game performance.

Comment: Okay, thank you. This isn't much of the game,though. The idea is that when you create a current, then the trident will tip forwards, like you pointed it, then it will create a signal which activates a current

Comment: This is the same as my answer... if you have extra information, i.e. letting the OP know that this is not mesh bonding, just joining, please do so in the comments area below the original answer.